I'm having issues with setting up flyway migrations with a postgres database
After hours of trials and tribulations, I'm trying to set up flyway migrations so I can easily create database tables within my project.
Here is my current POM file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-3.9.7.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>gown-qub-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>22</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>22</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jooq</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-postgres-extensions</artifactId>
            <version>3.19.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
            <version>3.19.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-testcontainers</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-commons</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.7</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>

                <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
                <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
                <version>3.19.9</version>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                        <version>42.7.3</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

                <configuration>
                    <jdbc>
                        <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                        <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres</url>
                        <user>user</user>
                        <password>password</password>
                    </jdbc>

                    <generator>
                        <database>
                            <name>org.jooq.meta.postgres.PostgresDatabase</name>
                            <includes>.*</includes>
                            <inputSchema>public</inputSchema>
                        </database>
                        <target>
                            <packageName>org.jooq.codegen.maven.example</packageName>
                            <directory>target/generated-sources/jooq</directory>
                        </target>
                    </generator>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>org.example.Application</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>22</source>
                    <target>22</target>
                    <release>22</release>
                    <compilerArgs>--enable-preview</compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
                <artifactId>testcontainers-jooq-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.4</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
                        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                        <version>1.19.3</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                        <version>42.7.3</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>10.15.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres</url>
                    <user>user</user>
                    <password>password</password>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>

(Excuse how messy it is - I'm but a student!)
Next, here is my application.properties file:
# ===================================================================
# APPLICATION PROPERTIES
# ===================================================================

# ----------------------------------------
# CORE PROPERTIES
# ----------------------------------------

# LOGGING
logging.level.root=DEBUG
logging.level.com.example=INFO
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=INFO
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=INFO

# THYMELEAF (ThymeleafAutoConfiguration)
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false

# ----------------------------------------
# WEB PROPERTIES
# ----------------------------------------

# EMBEDDED SERVER CONFIGURATION (ServerProperties)
server.port=8080
server.session.timeout=900

# MULTIPART (MultipartProperties)
multipart.max-file-size=10MB
multipart.max-request-size=100MB

# JACKSON (JacksonProperties)
spring.jackson.date-format=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

# ----------------------------------------
# SECURITY PROPERTIES
# ----------------------------------------
# SECURITY (SecurityProperties)
security.basic.enabled=false

# ----------------------------------------
# DATA PROPERTIES
# ----------------------------------------
# DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
#spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password

### test and validation for connection
spring.datasource.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.validation-query=SELECT 1
### remove connection when abolish
spring.datasource.remove-abandoned=true
spring.datasource.remove-abandoned-timeout=30
### Settings of Connection pool
spring.datasource.max-active=50
spring.datasource.max-idle=8
spring.datasource.min-idle=8
spring.datasource.initial-size=10
## Number of ms to wait before throwing an exception if no connection is available.
spring.datasource.max-wait=10000

# H2 Web Console (H2ConsoleProperties)
#spring.h2.console.enabled=false # Enable the console.
#spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console # Path at which the console will be available.

# JPA (JpaBaseConfiguration, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration)
#spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

#Flyway properties
spring.flyway.baseline-on-migrate=true
spring.flyway.enabled=true
spring.flyway.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.flyway.password=password
spring.flyway.user=user
spring.flyway.schemas=public
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration

And finally, here is the error message:
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: No database found to handle jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres

I've been pulling my hair out trying to get this to work; any ideas?
I had success getting the flyway schema history table to initialise; however upon using mvn flyway:migrate it seems to ignore my first migration file.
I then upgraded my postgres dependency versions across the board

it is saying No database found - have you started the database? Is it available on localhost? If you started it in docker, did you remember to publish the 5432 port?

You are mixing different spring boot versions. The parent says 3.3.0 while spring-boot-starter-logging says 3.2.4 fix that first... also those versions manually done for spring-security are the wrong way... just use them which are provided by spring boot parent... The versions for junit-jupiter etc. remove them also ... dependencies only junit-jupiter-engine and junit-jupiter-api are required. The version is already provided by spring boot parent... The usage of javax.servlet-api is wrong, because spring boot 3.0+ is on jakarta.*
